# How to get first not null element from ARRAY<string> in hive 2.2.0

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive SQL as below which returns the following output, now I want to get the first not null value from array i.e. "11".

SQ::

> select cod_cust, split(reverse(concat_ws('',collect_list(case when
>   acc_status='Dormant' then "1" else "0" end))),'0') status from
>   account_status group by cod_cust;

Output::

> cod_cust  status
>
> 1023  ["","11","1","111","",""]
>
> 2209  ["","11","1","111","",""]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `split` function the output would be look like:

```
cod_cust    status
1023        01101011100
2209        01101011100
```

So the task is to find the first subsequence of `1`, which can be solved by `regexp_extract`. Also you can use `IF` instead of `CASE`:

```
SELECT cod_cust, 
       regexp_extract(reverse(concat_ws('', collect_list(if((acc_status='Dormant'), '1', '0'))), '1+', 0) first_element
status 
FROM account_status 
GROUP BY cod_cust;
```

Comment: Thanks, Iskuskov, I just added the third parameter of regexp_extract as '0' it's working fine for me....     SELECT cod_cust, 
regexp_extract(reverse(concat_ws('', collect_list(if((acc_status='Dormant'), '1', '0')))), '1+',0) first_element
FROM account_status
GROUP BY cod_cust;                               thanks again

Comment: @Vivek, you are right! I've updated the post. If my answer is useful, vote up, pleas!